# Typescript function always returns parent object and not return value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Typescript object that defines a function. The object itself defines an array of some objects. So I am trying to add a function to act more like an indexer. The function always returns the parent object where it is defined and not a specific string value.

Here's the code. The variables is defined as an Array of object having name and value as properties.

```
    valueOf(key: string): string {
        var result = '';

        if (key === null || key === undefined || key.length === 0) {
            return result;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < this.variables.length; i++) {
            if (this.variables[i].name === key) {
                result = this.variables[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The above function is defined on a Typescript object. This object includes a property of type Array. I want to query that array based on a string key and not number key. That's why I wrote the above function to loop over the elements of property "variables", i.e. the Array, when there is a match on "name" === "key passed in", return the "value" associated with the object inside "variables property".

for instance, I can use the above as:

```
var tsObj = new TsObj(...);
tsObj.valueOf('key1');
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this code is supposed to do. Could you give a little more context or some sample usage to make it more clear?

Comment: [`Object#valueOf` already exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), you should reconsider your function name.

Comment: The function seems fine. can you put your code for the "variables" variable and the constructor.